# How to change window ratio in teachpress "tplist"

Tags: parameter

I am using teachPress to create list of publications.
Picture below is a result of this code:

```
[tplist order="title ASC" style="simple"
        year="2017" image="left" image_size="300"]
```

Is there any adjustable parameter to **divide window** (illustration/article detail into different ratio than 1/2 + 1/2?   For example to 1/3 + 2/3?

---

[image]

Comment: If you provided a link to a sample page, we could check to see whether the objective could be achieved via some simple CSS rather than with a new template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a custom template for displaying the publication.

Follow the documentation on how to do this.

https://github.com/winkm89/teachPress/wiki/Creating-templates